# Can I join urls using os.path.join() in Python or is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to navigate to different urls to download images from each of them.
The urls are sequential, so I thought best to manually creating them rather than using the Next button in each page.
I'm trying to generate the different section of the url and then join them together with os.path.join().

This is my working code:

```
starting_url = 'https://www.mangareader.net/one-piece'
storing_folder = '/Users/macbook/Documents/Media/Fumetti/One_Piece'
ch_numb_regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
for chapter in os.listdir(storing_folder):
    if not chapter.startswith('.'):
        if os.listdir(os.path.join(storing_folder, chapter)) == []:
            continue
        else:
            try:
                page = 1
                while True:
                    res = requests.get(os.path.join(starting_url, str(ch_numb_regex.search(chapter).group()) ,str(page)))
                    res.raise_for_status()
                    manga_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
                    manga_image = manga_soup.select('#imgholder img')
                    manga_url = manga_image[0].get('src')
                    res = requests.get(manga_url)
                    res.raise_for_status()
                    imageFile = open(os.path.join(storing_folder, chapter, page), 'wb')
                    imageFile.write()
                    imageFile.close()
                    page += 1
            except requests.HTTPError:
                continue
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-1ee22580435e> in <module>()
      7 res = requests.get(manga_url)
      8 res.raise_for_status()
----> 9 imageFile = open(os.path.join(storing_folder, chapter, page), 'wb')
     10 imageFile.write()
     11 imageFile.close()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py in join(a, *p)
     90                 path += sep + b
     91     except (TypeError, AttributeError, BytesWarning):
---> 92         genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
     93         raise
     94     return path

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py in _check_arg_types(funcname, *args)
    147         else:
    148             raise TypeError('%s() argument must be str or bytes, not %r' %
--> 149                             (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
    150     if hasstr and hasbytes:
    151         raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None

TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int'
```

But they should all be strings.

Comment: Your `page` variable is definitely an int. The error says they need to all be strings

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It seems to me that only about 3 lines in your code are relevant.

Comment: I certainly woundn't use `os.path.join` for URLs. If you're on windows it'll insert `'\\'` instead of `'/'`.

Comment: I know page is a an int, that's why I use str(page)

Comment: I'm on Mac, so it should use '/'

Answer (score 3):

> Can I join urls using `os.path.join()` in Python [...]?

Not portably, no. In the case of non-Unix operating systems, the path separator will not be `'/'`, so you'll create malformed URIs.

> [...] is there a better way?

Yes. You can use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin).

Comment: but I'm on a Mac, so the separator will be /

Comment: Why not use the tool that actually solves the problem _always_ instead of sometimes?

Comment: As an aside, you asked a question and I gave an answer. If you'd like to debate, StackOverflow might not be the best place.

Comment: Because the code it's meant only for me, but i see your point.
However, you did not give me an answer, you just told where should I look for one. I'm really new at Python, so if you could be more precise with the use of urllib it would be appreciated.